# To find maximum and minimum of a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, max, minimum

```
domains
    list = integer*//shows error in swish saying "syntax error operator
                     expected"
    Max = integer
predicates
    maximum_no(list,integer)
clauses
    maximum_no([],Max):-
        write("Maximum No in List is:: ",Max),nl.
    maximum_no([H|T],Max):-
        H>Max,
        N = H,
        maximum_no(T,N).
    maximum_no(L,Max):-
        maximum_no(L,Max).
```

Can someone please tell me how do I solve this error ? I do find the code is correct but it still says an error?
I also have to write the code to find the minimum number of a list!!

Comment: okay so it appears you are using **visual prolog**. Try adding a dot (`.`)  after each line in the `domains` section and in the `predicates` section.

Answer (score 0):

The following alone works in order to find the max of a list :

```
% the maximum of a list of one element is this element
maximum_no([X],X).

% the maximum of a list is either the head or the maximum of the tail
% depending on if the head is lower than the max of the tail.
maximum_no([H|T],Max):-
    maximum_no(T,Max),
    H @< Max.
maximum_no([Max|T],Max):-
    maximum_no(T,M),
    M @< Max.
```

Then, finding the min of a list shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: even then its throwing an error. saying a missing operator! Also is there a way to write both minimum and maximum of a list in prolog?

Comment: @ChetanGrandhe Did you check my edit ? Then if `maximum_no/2` works, all you have to do is write a `minimum_no/2` and `minmax_no/3` as follows : `minmax_no(L,Min,Max) :- minimum_no(L,Min), maximum_no(L,Max).`

Comment: thanks @Rafalon for the reply, But I still get an error saying OPERATOR EXPECTED. Did you try executing that code in http://swish.swi-prolog.org/     ????

Comment: Apparently swish isn't for **visual prolog** so when I use http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/NybYBrJV.pl it seems to work.

Comment: @ChetanGrandhe please try and tell me if it fits your requirements, then feel free to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. For the minimum just make the proper changes.

maximum_no([H|T],Max):-
    maximum_no(T,MX),
    Max is max(H,MX).